# Flow of fluid in branched pipes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

Could any one please tell me if there is any flow possible into pipe 2. What I believe is that as pipe 1 and pipe 3 are of same diameter and applying Bernoulli's equation between points 1 and 3 gives us that velocities in pipe 1 and pipe 3 must be same and based on continuity equation Q1=Q2+Q3 we get Q2=0, is it correct?
[image]

Comment: Consider pressure drop ie losses.

Comment: Hi Mike, it is case of inviscid and incompressible flow and that is the reason I neglected any losses in the pipe. I believe that there will be no flow in pipe 2, do u agree?

Comment: No, I don’t agree. Check out what I said in my comment. If you are correct then a lot of taps plumbed with tees won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Why assume Q1(Mass flow rate through opening 1)=Q3(Mass flow rate through opening 3)? The tee pipe itself impedes at least some flow between points 1 and 3 (flow rate would be at least slightly faster if this tee did not exist, shortening the overall run of pipe) and so the tee imposes some forces on the fluid.

In particular, consider the pressure that the tee imposes on the fluid on the wall opposing 2. Some other force must prevent this from redirecting at least some flow out 2 (such as pressure at 2, gravity imposed or otherwise).

As for two things of the same diameter having the same flow, that only holds if there is nowhere else for the mass to escape, ie 2.  If fluid flows from 1 to 3, and some fluid flows out 2, the flow out 3 will simply be less than the flow through 1 by that amount.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume branch 2 is high enough so that the hydrostatic pressure of water column in 2 compensates the dynamic pressure of the horizontal flow, nothing flows out from 2.

If 2 is not high enough some liquid is lost via branch 2. That's how much the flow is smaller in branch 3 than in branch 1. How much - that depends on the height of 2 and how much it causes friction due the viscosity and limited diameter. A complex thing to be estimated, I'd say.